# How do I display posts of a specific day?

Tags: ajax, query-posts, archives

```
<?php

/* AJAX.php */

//ajax call with no privalidges, a user that is not logged can access load-more
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_japi_load_more','japi_load_more');
add_action('wp_ajax_japi_load_more','japi_load_more');
function japi_load_more(){
  $year = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['digwp_y']));
  $month = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['digwp_m']));
  $day = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['digwp_d']));



  query_posts(array('year'=>$year,'monthnum'=>$month,'day'=>$day,'posts_per_page'=>-1 ));

            if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();

          ?>

            <?php get_template_part('content',get_post_format()); ?>

        <?php
            endwhile; else:

                echo "<p style='text-align: center; font-size: 15px; padding: 5px;'>Nothing found.</p>";

            endif;


    wp_reset_postdata();

    die();
}
```

Comment: Hi. Welcome to WPSE. I've posted an answer for you, but please take a moment and read [how to ask](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) page for your future questions. A single block of code is not considered a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First things first. Do not you `query_posts()`. Use [`WP_Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Date_Parameters) instead, to prevent messing with the main query.

Now, as for your question. `WP_Query` allows you to enter data parameters too. It even has a date query which you can check it out in the link I've provided.

Instead of using Admin-AJAX, you can write a simple REST-API endpoint for you that is faster, simpler, and does the same (even more!). But since the content of your template is unknown to me, I'm gonna skip this.

So, let's turn your code into this:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_japi_load_more','japi_load_more');
add_action('wp_ajax_japi_load_more','japi_load_more');
function japi_load_more(){
    // Get the parameters
    $year = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['digwp_y']));
    $month = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['digwp_m']));
    $day = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['digwp_d']));
    // Set the date in the Query
    $args = array(
            'posts_per_page'    => -1
            'year'              => $year,
            'monthnum'          => $month, // Number of the month, not name
            'day'               => $day,
    );
    $query = new WP_Query($args);
    //Run the loop
    if( $query->have_posts() ) {
        while( $query->have_posts() ){
            $query->the_post();
            get_template_part('content',get_post_format());
        }
    } else {
         echo "<p style='text-align: center; font-size: 15px; padding: 5px;'>".__('Nothing found.','text-domain')."</p>";
    }
}
```